# ¿Como evitar el bloqueo de un archivo despues de usar ese archivo?

Tags: python, django, imagen, bloqueo

Tengo un problema, estoy diseñando una app con python en Django que me permita leer los archivos de una carpeta que son imagenes, posteriormente les cambiara el tamaño y finalmente quiero que los mueva a otra carpeta de archivos procesados.

El problema esta en que el codigo lee las imagenes y las redimensiona, pero no las cambia de carpeta (aunque las copia) ya que me indica que:

**"El proceso no tiene acceso al archivo porque está siendo utilizado por otro proceso:"** y necesito que se eliminen de la carpeta original no solo que se copien.

Les comparto el codigo para ver si tengo algun error.

He intentado:

- Colocar un delay para esperar que se desocupen los archivos
- un codigo para reintentar varias veces si el archivo se encuentra ocupado.
- probé primero a copiar los archivos y despues redimensionarlos, pero
  sucede lo mismo.

Agradeceria mucho su ayuda.

```
def archivo(request):

  if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES.getlist('archivo'):
    archivos = request.FILES.getlist('archivo')
 
    carpeta_entrada = "C:\\carpeta\\de\\entrada\\"
    carpeta_salida = "C\\carpeta\\de\\salida\\"
    carpeta_procesados = "C:\\carpeta\\de\\procesadas\\"
    
    
    nuevo_tamaño = (1024, 768)  

    for archivo in archivos:
        if archivo.name.endswith((".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".gif")): 
           
            ruta_entrada = os.path.join(carpeta_entrada, archivo.name)
            ruta_procesados = os.path.join(carpeta_procesados, archivo.name)
            
            max_retries = 1
            retry_delay = 1  

            for i in range(max_retries):
                try:
                    shutil.move(ruta_entrada, ruta_procesados)
                    print("Archivo movido y eliminado exitosamente")
                    print("intento", i)
                    print("movido")
                    break  
                
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Error al mover el archivo: {e}")
                    print("intento ", i)
                    time.sleep(retry_delay)

            # Redimensiona la imagen
            imagen = Image.open(ruta_procesados)
            imagen_redimensionada = imagen.resize(nuevo_tamaño)

         
            ruta_salida = os.path.join(carpeta_salida, archivo.name)
            imagen_redimensionada.save(ruta_salida)
            print("Imagen redimensionada y guardada")

    return HttpResponse("Imágenes redimensionadas y archivos originales movidos y eliminados exitosamente")

return HttpResponse("No se han subido archivos o se utilizó un método de solicitud incorrecto.")
```

Comment: Buen día, el problema es relativamente sencillo, cuando manipulas archivos con `python` si utilizas `open` debes utilizar `close`. Otro método es utilizar `with` que cerrará el archivo al finalizar el proceso, [lectura recomendada](https://geekflare.com/es/handle-files-in-python/).

Comment: Intente agregando "imagen.close()" como el comentario de abajo y con "with" pero el resultado es el mismo.
No se si este implementando mal algo o sea por que cargo las imagenes con un formulario en el html pero el error sigue apareciendo intentare dividir la funcion en 2 a ver si lo logro, aun asi muchas gracias por el apoyo

Answer (score 0):

Después de la línea

```
imagen = Image.open(ruta_procesados)
        imagen_redimensionada = imagen.resize(nuevo_tamaño)
```

Necesitas cerrar el recurso y liberar el archivo antes de moverlo.

Necesitas

```
imagen.close()
```

Así se libera el archivo y se puede proceder a mover, también libera la memoria porque sin cerrarlo los archivos están cargados en memoria. Este mismo concepto aplica a conexiones de red, bases de datos, sockets , etc. Si hay un método Open hay un método Close.

Comment: Gracias lo intente agregando el "imagen.close()", pero vuelve al mismo problema
“Error al mover el archivo: [WinError 32] El proceso no tiene acceso al archivo por que esta siendo utilizado por otro proceso”
Quiero imaginar que tal vez el problema sea en como cargo las imagenes (por medio de un formulario) lo que esta causando el conflicto
Intentare dividir la funcion en 2 para ver si asi me lo permite.
Gracias